# Visually explaining limit properties.

Tags: limits, visualization

I was doing the start of the calculus section from khan academy. I couldn't properly understand the limit properties.

Limit properties: https://miro.medium.com/max/565/0*9pLbmbpHrva-LtMe.png

I searched a lot for a graphical explanation of these properties and how the limit work with composite functions, but couldn't find a visual explanation telling me why these properties are true.

This is quite a basic thing but I really think a visual explanation will help me understand it better.

Comment: For example, for the sum rule, if $f(x)$ is getting really close to $L$ and $g(x)$ is getting really close to $M$, it makes sense that $f(x) + g(x)$ is getting really close to $L+M$.

Answer (score 0):

These properties come from the following basic facts:

- When $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=M$ then $\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)$ is near $(L,M)$ when $x$ is near $c$.
- The arithmetic operations $+$, $-$, $*$, $:$ (when defined) are continuous. This means that when $a'$ is near $a$ and $b'$ is near $b$, then $a'\cdot b'$  is near $a\cdot b$, for all four operations.

Comment: I was hoping to find a source where I can see a visual representation(especially for composite functions). As I'm trying to self learn this, I am really having a hard time finding the right sources. I would really appreciate any reference to a good source.